# How to get certain values from json(converted as a text)

Tags: java, json

I got   json in a string    format  and i want to  take certain values  from  it  i  don't  want  to use JSONObject and related org.json   implementation , here is  what  i  am trying:

```
String  text=execution.getVariable("documents").toString();
     String  finalResult=text.substring( text.indexOf(":")+1,text.length());
     String Final2=finalResult.replaceAll("=", ":");
     String Fin3=Final2.replace("[","");
     String Fin4=Fin3.replace("]", "");
     System.out.println(Fin4);
     System.out.println(Fin4.substring(Fin4.indexOf("id"),Fin4.indexOf(",")));
```

here  is  my  json(formated as a string) input  example:

```
[{id:1,"name":"olovia","age":34}];
```

and i  want  to  get all  this  (id, name,age)  values from this string, how  should  i  do  it  without  substring ?

Comment: Have you considered using a parsing library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)?

Answer (score 1):

You should really reconsider using a json parser for your usecase.

But if you really want to do it manually, you should use regex rather than substrings :

```
 @Test
    public void should_find_key() throws Exception {
       String input = "[{id:1,\"name\":\"olovia\",\"age\":34}]";
       Assertions.assertThat(extract("name", input)).isEqualTo("olovia");
    }

    private String extract(String key, String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"" + key + "\":\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return  matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you avoiding `JSONObject`? 
Do you know that the quick route, sometimes, becomes the longest and most dangerous?

I quote @chess4ever, let's look at Gson library if you are not comfortable with `JSONObject`.